# How to run shiny rmd file from jupyterlab

Tags: bash, shiny, r-markdown, jupyter-lab

I have a shiny rmd file which is working in the RStudio IDE. However, I have to include it as part of a pipeline so I have to run it through Jupyterlab.

I have the runtime: shiny at the start of my rmd file:

```
title: "X"
runtime: shiny
output: 
  html_document:
    theme: flatly
    toc: yes
    toc_float:
      collapsed: true
```

And then in my .ipynb file I'm running:

```
%%bash
R -e "library(rmarkdown); rmarkdown::run('X.Rmd', shiny_args = list(launch.browser = TRUE))"
```

And I get as far as

Loading required package: shiny
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:3158

Does anyone have any advice? Let me know if you need more info to answer.

````
---
title: "X"
runtime: shiny
output: 
  html_document:
    theme: flatly
    toc: yes
    toc_float:
      collapsed: true

---

```{r setup, context="setup", include=FALSE}

knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
library(renv)
library(rmarkdown)
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)
library(stringr)
library(data.table)
library(shiny)
library(magrittr)
library(readxl)
library(prismatic)
library(tidyr)
library(RColorBrewer)
```

```{r data prep, echo=FALSE, context="data"}

#############
# DATA PREP #
#############
sampleSheet <- read.csv("XXX.csv", sep = ",", header = F)
colnames(sampleSheet) <- c("original_sample", "V1", "V2")
sampleKey <- read_excel("XXX.xlsx")

sampleSheet$file <- substring(sampleSheet$V1, 22, 36)
sampleSheet <- data.table(sampleSheet)
sampleSheet <-
  sampleSheet[complete.cases(sampleSheet), .(original_sample, file)]

sampleSheet <- sampleSheet %>%
  inner_join(sampleKey
             , by = c("original_sample" = "original_sample_name"))

#####################
# Read quality logs #
#####################

qualFiles <- list.files(#path = paste(dir, "/", "bcr-data", sep = ""),
                        path = paste("./", "bcr-data", sep = ""),
                        pattern = 'quality_log_table.tab$',
                        full.names = TRUE)

qualLst <- lapply(qualFiles, fread)
for( i in seq_along(qualLst)){
  qualLst[[i]]$FILE <- substr(basename(qualFiles)[i], 1, 15)
}

qualityData <- do.call(rbind, Map(cbind, index = seq_along(qualLst), qualLst))

# Join quality files to sample sheeet
qualityData <-  qualityData %>% 
  inner_join(sampleSheet
             , by = c("FILE" = "file"))

qualityData <- as.data.table(qualityData)
setDT(qualityData)
#str(qualityData)
# Create summary statistics table
qualSumStats <- qualityData[, as.list(summary(QUALITY)), by = FILE]

qualSumStats <- left_join(qualSumStats, 
                          sampleSheet[, c("donor", "treatment", "file")], 
                          by = join_by(FILE == file)) %>% distinct()

# save as RDS 
#saveRDS(qualSumStats, file = "qualSumStats.RDS")

##################################
# Read constant region log files #
##################################

ccallFiles <- list.files(#path = paste(dir, "/", "bcr-data", sep = ""),
                         path = paste("./", "bcr-data", sep = ""),
                         pattern = 'c_call_log_table.tab$',
                         full.names = TRUE)

ccallLst <- lapply(ccallFiles, fread)
for( i in seq_along(ccallLst)){
  ccallLst[[i]]$FILE <- substr(basename(ccallFiles)[i], 1, 15)
}

ccallData <- do.call(rbind, Map(cbind, index = seq_along(ccallLst), ccallLst))

ccallData <-  ccallData %>% 
  inner_join(sampleSheet
             , by = c("FILE" = "file"))

countIsotype <- ccallData %>%
  group_by(donor) %>%
  count(PRIMER) 

countIsotype <-
  left_join(countIsotype, sampleSheet[, c("donor", "treatment")], by = join_by(donor == donor), relationship = "many-to-many") %>% distinct()

#saveRDS(countIsotype, file = "countIsotype_test.RDS")

##########################
# Consensus Sequence Log #
##########################

## read in files and name based on sample
conFiles <- list.files(#path = paste(dir, "/", "bcr-data", sep = ""),
                       path = paste("./", "bcr-data", sep = ""),
                       pattern = 'consensus_log_table.tab$',
                       full.names = TRUE)

conLst <- lapply(conFiles, fread)
for( i in seq_along(conLst)){
  conLst[[i]]$FILE <- substr(basename(conFiles)[i], 1, 15)
}

conData <- do.call(rbind, Map(cbind, index = seq_along(conLst), conLst))

conData %<>%
  group_by(FILE) %>% 
  mutate('UMI Sequencing Depth' = n_distinct(BARCODE) / sum(CONSCOUNT, na.rm = T)) 

conData <-  conData %>% 
  inner_join(sampleSheet
             , by = c("FILE" = "file"))

conData %<>% select(FILE, 'UMI Sequencing Depth', donor) %>% distinct()


#source(paste(dir, "/", "BCR-Log-Data-Prep.R",sep = ""))

choices <- levels(as.factor(qualityData$donor))

```


<br>
<br>

## Donor Selection
```{r sampleSelect, echo=FALSE}

selectInput(
    "donorSelect"
    , label = "Select Donor(s):"
    , choices = choices #c("S04","S05","S06","S07")
    , selected = choices #c("S04","S05","S06","S07")
    , multiple = T
    )

```

<br>

## Phred Quality Score Log

<br>

```{r phred, echo=FALSE,fig.align='center', context="server"}

#qualityData <- readRDS("./data/qualSumStats.RDS") 
qualSumStats <- as.data.table(qualSumStats)

qualSumStatsReact <-
  reactive({
    req(input$donorSelect)

    qualDat <-
      qualSumStats[qualSumStats$donor %in% input$donorSelect, ]

    return(qualDat)
  })


renderPlotly({
qualBoxplot <-
  plot_ly(
    x = c(qualSumStatsReact()[, FILE])
    ,
    type = "box"
    ,
    color = ~ c(qualSumStatsReact()[, donor])
    ,
    colors = brewer.pal(length(names(table(qualSumStatsReact()[, donor]))),
               "Paired")
    ,
    showlegend = T
    ,
    q1 = qualSumStatsReact()[, `1st Qu.`]
    ,
    median = qualSumStatsReact()[, Median]
    ,
    q3 = qualSumStatsReact()[, `3rd Qu.`]
    ,
    lowerfence = qualSumStatsReact()[, Min.]
    ,
    upperfence = qualSumStatsReact()[, Max.]
    ,
    mean = qualSumStatsReact()[, Mean]
    
  ) %>%
  layout(
    yaxis = list(
      title = 'Phred Score'
    )
    ,
    xaxis = list(
      title = 'Sample'
      ,
      autotick = F
      ,
      tickmode = "array"
      ,
      tickvals = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
      ,
      ticktext = c(qualSumStatsReact()[, c(FILE)])
      ,
      yaxis = list(title = 'Phred Score', range = c(-5, 40))
    )
    ,
    legend = list(title=list(text='<b> Donor </b>'))
  )


print(qualBoxplot)

})

```

<br>
<br>

***

<br>
<br>

## Constant Region Log

<br>

```{r c_call, echo=FALSE, fig.align='center', context="server"}

#countIsotype <- readRDS("./data/countIsotype_test.RDS")
countIsotype <- as.data.table(countIsotype)

## read in files and name based on sample
countIsotypeReact <-
  reactive({
    req(input$donorSelect)
    
    countIsotypeDat <-
      countIsotype[countIsotype$donor %in% input$donorSelect, ]
    
    return(countIsotypeDat)
  })

renderPlotly({
  isotype_barplt <- plot_ly(
    data = countIsotypeReact()
    ,
    x = ~ donor
    ,
    y = ~ n
    ,
    type = "bar"
    ,
    color = ~ factor(PRIMER)
    ,
    colors = "Blues"
  ) %>%  layout(
    yaxis = list(title = 'Count')
    ,
    barmode = 'stack'
    ,
    xaxis = list(title = 'Donor')
    ,
    title = list(text = "<b> Isotype Count </b>")
    ,
    legend = list(title = list(text = '<b> Isotype </b>'))
    ,
    showlegend = T
  )
  
print(isotype_barplt)
})

```


<br>
<br>

***

<br>
<br>

## UMI Sequencing Depth

<br>

```{r consensus, echo=FALSE, fig.align='center', context="server"}

#conData <- readRDS("./data/conData_test.RDS")
conData <- as.data.table(conData)

condataReact <- reactive({
    req(input$donorSelect)
    
    conDat <- conData[conData$donor %in% input$donorSelect,]
    
    return(conDat)
  })

renderPlotly({
conBarplt <- plot_ly(
  x = c(condataReact()$FILE)
  ,
  y = condataReact()$`UMI Sequencing Depth`
  ,
  type = "bar"
  ,
  color = ~ condataReact()$donor
  ,
  colors = 
    brewer.pal(length(names(table(
    condataReact()$donor))), "Paired")
) %>% layout(
  yaxis = list(title =  "UMI Sequencing Depth ")
  ,
  xaxis = list(title = 'Sample', tickangle = 45)
  #,
  #title = list(text = "<b> UMI Sequencing Depth </b>")
  ,
  legend = list(title = list(text = '<b> Donor </b>'))
)

print(conBarplt)

})
```
````

Dummy Data:

```
qualSumStats <- data.frame(FILE = c("x", "y", "z"),
                  `Min.` = c(11, 11, 11),
                  `1st Qu.` = c(25, 25, 25),
                  Median = c(28, 28, 28),
                  Mean = c(27.82580, 27.81644, 27.85037 ),
                  `3rd Qu.` = c(32, 32, 32),
                  `Max.` = c(34, 34, 34),
                  donor = c("S03","S04","S05"),
                  treatment = c("Treated","Treated","PBO")
                  )

countIsotype <- data.frame(donor = c("S03","S04","S05"),
                  PRIMER = c("IGHA", "IGHD", "IGHM"),
                  n = c(520010, 28064, 433),
                  treatment = c("Treated","Treated","PBO")
)

conData <- data.frame(FILE = c("x", "y", "z"),
                  `UMI Sequencing Depth` = c(0.05970393, 0.04421778, 0.09510608),
                  donor = c("S03","S04","S05")
)
```

Comment: This may sound odd and maybe you've already tried this, but once you get to that step try leaving your Rconsole like that and opening http://127.0.0.1:3158 in your web browser. Just type that link into your address bar and see if anything is there.

Comment: @Quinton.Quagliano Yeah I tried that, just get:  Hmmm… can't reach this page127.0.0.1 refused to connect.
Try:

Search Bing for 127 0 0 1
Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall

Comment: Okay, was worth a try. If you could, please post the code from your shiny app here so that we can troubleshoot - without it it's impossible to know what may be causing the error

Comment: @Quinton.Quagliano I've edited my post so it has my full .Rmd file code!

Comment: thank you -  could you also post a subset of your data so that I am able to use it in the document? Otherwise I won't be able to get to the point to replicate your original error.

Comment: @Quinton.Quagliano - Just edited it so it has some dummy data! Just the final dataframes that are used for the plots. Thanks so much